# Best way to retrieve active calls without making request each second?

Tags: ringcentral

We need to create a monitor that will show any income calls in our extranet in live time.

We were able to show active calls by using `/account/~/extension/~/active-calls`, however, to achieve what we need we would need to make a request each second which I guess will be blocked by rate limits.

Is there a better solution for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Subscription (**Push Notification**) API resource empowers developers to enable the client application(s) to create a single subscription (to one or more extension's) and continually receive push notifications in real time for each subscribed extension.When using this approach for your application(s) to receive events on your RingCentral account, no polling is involved.

You can create a subscription using either of the below-mentioned transportType for receiving push notifications:

- PubNub
- WebHook

Notifications which the client wants to receive can be specified by the event filters which are set in the subscription request. The event filter is exposed as a URL, pointing to the required RingCentral API resource. Currently the following event types are available for notifications: extensions, messages and presence. They are described in detail below:
[Notifications Event Types](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#EventTypes.html)

You can take a look at the Subscription API below:
[Subscription API](https://developer.ringcentral.com/api-docs/latest/index.html#!#RefNotifications.html)

If you are interested in Subscribing to Push notifications via WebHook then we have an Easy-to-follow Quickstart guide here:
[RingCentral Webhooks Quickstart Guide](http://ringcentral-quickstart.readthedocs.io/en/latest/webhooks/#webhooks)